# Eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue 1 in the Normalized Laplacian - Why does it represent clusters?

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, clustering

Consider the Normalized Laplacian associated to a similarty graph
$$
L = D^{-1/2}SD^{-1/2}
$$

I have two sources stating that, in the "ideal case of zero noise", the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue 1 (or near 1) represent clusters (while the eigenvectors corresponding to 0 represent connected components, as it is known).

> *Clustering of Vehicle Trajectories*, Stefan Atev, Grant Miller, and Nikolaos Papanikolopoulos, IEEE Transactions on Intelligent
> Transportation Systems · October 2010
>
> *Self-Tuning Spectral Clustering*, Lihi Zelnik-Manor, January 2004 Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 17 Conference:
> Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems (NIPS)

I really can't understand why. How can I see this?